# Error while displaying image path from database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, image

I am trying display images on webpage, where image path stored in database and images is stored in server.But i am not able to display those images using following codes, so pls somebody help me with this issue,..

```
<form method="post"  enctype="multipart/form-data" action="file_upload.php">
<table>

<?php

$dbhost = 'xxxxxxxx';
$dbuser = 'xxxxxxxxx';
$dbpass = 'xxxxxxxxxx';
$db_name = 'xxxxxxxxxx';
$tbl_name = 'imagetype1';

$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);

if(! $conn )
{
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

$query1 = mysql_query("select * from '$tbl_name' where id='1'");  //Error
$rows1 = mysql_fetch_array($query1);
$path1 = $rows1['image'];

$query2 = mysql_query("select * from '$tbl_name' where id='2'");  //Error
$rows2 = mysql_fetch_array($query2);
$path2 = $rows2['image'];

$query3 = mysql_query("select * from '$tbl_name' where id='3'");  //Error
$rows3 = mysql_fetch_array($query3);
$path3 = $rows3['image'];

echo '<tr><td><img src="$path1"></td>' ;
echo '<td><img src="$path2"></td>' ;
echo '<td><img src="$path3"></td></tr>' ;

?>

</form>
</table>
```

***Error***

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''imagetype1' where id='1'' at line 1

[image]

Comment: What is the datatype of the column ID in the table imagetype1?

Comment: Remove the quotes around all `'$tbl_name'` those aren't the correct identifiers.

Comment: try this: "select * from {$tbl_name} where id='1'" ...When you use {$somevar} in double quoted string your variable name is expanded ...more information is http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
mysql_query("select * from '$tbl_name' where id='1'");
```

to

```
mysql_query("select * from ".$tbl_name." where id='1'");
```

Comment: Thanx got it after long questioning,..

Answer (score 0):

Don't use quote characters (') surrounding your table name in your query.